# How to add new property to a custom Edge shape

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

I need to add a new property to a custom Edge shape (which extends `mxConnector`) to change color of the Edge, basing on that property value.
Example is below:

```
function ExecutorEdge()
{
    mxConnector.call(this);
};
mxUtils.extend(ExecutorEdge, mxConnector);
ExecutorEdge.prototype.customProperties = [
    {name: 'trxSort', dispName: 'Transaction Sort', type: 'enum', defVal:'orig',
        enumList:[
            {val:'orig', dispName:'Original'},
            {val:'info', dispName:'Informational'},
            {val:'doc', dispName:'Documental'}
        ]}
];

mxCellRenderer.registerShape('executorEdge', ExecutorEdge);
```

I managed to do the same thing for custom shape which extends `mxEllipse` but with Edge the property doesn't even occur on properties table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was setting my new shape to `endArrow` property not `shape`. Using the code in question description and creating Edge template as below works fine. New custom property is addedd successfully.

```
this.createEdgeTemplateEntry('shape=executorEdge;html=1;', 50, 50, '', 'Executor Link', null, tags)
```